# Unable to start WSO2 ESB after deactivating the Message Forwarding Processor and deleting a sample endpoint and proxy service

Tags: wso2-esb

I am using WSO2 ESB 4.6.0, Debain GNU/Linux, WSO2 MessageBroker 2.0.1.

I have the following issue when I try to start WSO2 ESB:

```
  [2013-06-21 04:19:17,370] FATAL - **ServiceBusInitializer Couldn't initialize the ESB...
  org.apache.synapse.message.processors.forward.ScheduledMessageForwardingProcessor.init(ScheduledMessageForwardingProcessor.java:76)
  ...
  [2013-06-21 04:20:16,589]  WARN - StartupFinalizerServiceComponent Waiting for required OSGi services: org.wso2.carbon.mediation.initializer.services.SynapseEnvironmentService
```

Any help in this regard will be appreciated.

Comment: seeing your code (or better yet, a small test case which shows the issue) would probably help

Comment: When I tried to implement the Use case Scenario 1 from the below link    http://docs.wso2.org/wiki/display/ESB460/Store+and+Forward+Using+JMS+Message+Stores                                                           I got the following errors:                                                       ERROR - JMSMessageStore JMS error while retrieving messages from the store: JMSMS
AMQConnection Unable to connect to broker at tcp://localhost:5673
When I deleted end point,proxyservice and deactivated Msg Forwarding Processor,I am getting above error

Answer (score 2):

A similar error has already been reported at https://wso2.org/jira/browse/ESBJAVA-2060

In this case what happens is even though you've deactivated the Message Processor, all Message Processors get reactivated at startup. And when it can't find the Message Store referred by the Message Processor, it throws an error. To get the ESB started you will have to delete the Message Processor also.

Go to `ESB_HOME/repository/deployment/server/synapse-configs/default/message-stores` folder and delete the XML file corresponding to your Message Processor. Then start the ESB. Then add the Message Stores and Processors as you want.